# oracle perl and system perl install side by side

Tags: oracle, perl

I installed oracle, and there is a conflict between oracles version of perl and system perl. I want to leave system perl where it is (working, and NOT a soft link to oracles perl) and I want oracle to just point to its perl. I know this can be done but finding an answer online has been hard. What is the standard procedure for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Just use the path to the desired instance of `perl`.

```
$ /usr/bin/perl -E'say "This is the system Perl. $]"'
This is the system Perl. 5.014002

$ 5.20.1t/bin/perl -E'say "This isn'\''t. $]"'
This isn't. 5.020001

$ 5.22.0t/bin/perl -E'say "Neither is this. $]"'
Neither is this. 5.022000
```